# Why does it say that my design is incomplete after using t3way?

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I am new to R and statistics and I really need some help.
I am trying to evaluate the Young's module I measured from my samples. My data looks like this:

I have two different Polymers (LDPE, PBAT/PLA), two different treatments (MAD/TAD) and time spent in the specific treatment Week (0,3,6). I have three measurements per sample.
My data is not normal distributed and there is heteroscedasticity. So I wanted to use a robust ANOVA, a three-way factorial ANOVA with the WRS2 package. But as soon as I use the t3way() function, I get this warning:

```
t3way(slope ~ Polymer*Week*Experiment, data=mydataTemp2)
```

Incomplete design! It needs to be full factorial!

My variables are all factors, except for slope. I also tried changing slope to factor too and I still got the same warning.

Can someone help? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error is from the data you are using, but it has to do with the relationship between the variables.

Using the example for the function `t3way()`:

```
t3way(aggressive ~ degree * gender * type, data = movie)
```

The model processes without an issue. (As the example, so no brainer, right?)

Tabling two factors at a time:

```
table(movie$degree, movie$gender)
#             male female
#   no degree   18     16
#   degree      18     16 

table(movie$degree, movie$type)
#             violent nonviolent
#   no degree      17         17
#   degree         17         17 

table(movie$gender, movie$type)
#          violent nonviolent
#   male        18         18
#   female      16         16
```

However, if I were to modify this to remove all `gender == "female"` and `degree == "degree"` this would look differently:

```
movie[-which(movie$gender == "female" & movie$degree == "degree",
             arr.ind = T),] %>% table(movie$gender, movie$degree)
```

Because there is a factor that doesn't 'cross' (no female & degree), you'll get this error:

```
Error in table(., movie$gender, movie$degree) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
In addition: Warning message:
In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
```

The function `t3way()` won't work either:

```
t3way(aggressive ~ degree * gender * type, 
      data = movie[-which(movie$gender == "female" & movie$degree == "degree",
                          arr.ind = T),])
```

You'll see the same error you saw:

```
Error in t3way(aggressive ~ degree * gender * type, data = movie[-which(movie$gender ==  : 
  Incomplete design! It needs to be full factorial!
```

To fix this, you could look to see what groups don't exist in your data. Potentially, you could use a 2-way ANOVA. Additionally, this is a *between groups* method of analysis. Some of what you're looking for is *within groups.* So there are a lot of other options.
Lastly, this function looks for interaction effects, when using traditional ANOVA, you can use a 3-way ANOVA without analyzing interactions. You may be able to find an alternative set of functions - there may be other methods of assumption-less ANOVA, without interactions.